# weakly compact subsets of a Banach space are relative weak topology

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let X be a Banach space and $X^*$ is separable. Show that if K is a weakly compact subset of X, then K with the relative weak topology is metrizable.

I can easily show that K with the weak topology is metrizable. Is it sufficient?

I think about a homeomorphism between K and the closed Ball X, then closed Ball X is weakly compact, which show that X is reflexive. Now by reflexivity of $X^*$, Ball X and K with the relative weak topology are metrizable. but I can not define a homeomorphism. Also I think K can be finite and in this case there isn't any homeomorhism.

Please help me.
Thanks so much

Comment: $K$ need not be homeomorphic to the closed unit ball (and if $X$ is not reflexive, it cannot be).

Comment: so what can I prove it?

Comment: How do you prove that the closed unit ball of a separable reflexive Banach space is metrisable in the weak topology?

Comment: Oh, I thought about it before. Thanks so much.